# Assign to a variable in the condition of a while loop - scala

Tags: scala, while-loop

I Java I can write this:

```
Matcher m;
while ((m = pattern.matcher(string)).matches()) {...}
```

How would I do this in Scala? This doesn't work :

```
var m: Matcher = null
while ((m = pattern.matcher(s)).matches()) {}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assignments return `Unit` in Scala, but it's ok to use code blocks like this:

```
while ({
  val m = pattern.matcher(s)
  m.matches
}) { ... }
```

Comment: If I want to use the val m in the body of the loop?

Comment: @Sohaib As I know there's no clean way to do it without using `var`. But if you're ok with that you may just use this: `var m: Matcher = null; while ({ m = pattern.matcher(s); m.matches}) { ... }`

Comment: yeah, it looks ugly, I always use breakable loop which throws exception. Did they fix it in dotty?